# How to properly release .NET objects exposed to COM?

Tags: c#, .net, com, vb6, com-interop

So I'm trying to expose a .NET object to COM for use in one of our legacy VB6 apps. I believe I've set up the .NET class correctly, as I can work with it in VB6 now, however I don't think I'm releasing all references to the COM object when my VB6 app closes/crashes. This is a very event-driven .NET object, and we've been seeing odd issues where a previous instantiation of our .NET object receives an event intended for a newer instantiation of said object.

To test this, I added trace writers to my .NET object. These traces print out the `Stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds` property of a local stopwatch I'm using to track the lifetime of the .NET object, as well as a GUID that is created new on each instantiation of the .NET object.

The first instantiation of this object (through VB6) looks like:

> 0 >>> Instantiated Phone <<< 7afc50d3-c33d-4c39-a84c-132feeefefa5
>
> 90 >>> Entered AgentLogin <<< 7afc50d3-c33d-4c39-a84c-132feeefefa5
>
> 90 >>> Creating CTISoftphone <<< 7afc50d3-c33d-4c39-a84c-132feeefefa5
>
> 103 >>> Subscribing to PhoneEvent <<< 7afc50d3-c33d-4c39-a84c-132feeefefa5
>
> 106 >>> Subscribing to OnCreateCtiConf <<< 7afc50d3-c33d-4c39-a84c-132feeefefa5
>
> 106 >>> Waiting for task result. <<< 7afc50d3-c33d-4c39-a84c-132feeefefa5
>
> 1206 >>> Received event: OnCreateCTIConf : No message <<< 7afc50d3-c33d-4c39-a84c-132feeefefa5
>
> 1206 >>> OnCreateCtiConf was not null, firing event. <<< 7afc50d3-c33d-4c39-a84c-132feeefefa5
>
> 1211 >>> Calling LoginAgent <<< 7afc50d3-c33d-4c39-a84c-132feeefefa5
>
> 1219 >>> Unsubscribing from OnCreateCtiConf <<< 7afc50d3-c33d-4c39-a84c-132feeefefa5

Then, any subsequent attempts either work fine, or hang indefinitely. If we follow the same traces for the subsequent attempts that hang indefinitely, the output looks like:

> 0 >>> Entered AgentLogin <<< 8c820520-06d4-49e3-ba41-13d0638bfbfc
>
> 0 >>> Creating CTISoftphone <<< 8c820520-06d4-49e3-ba41-13d0638bfbfc
>
> 4 >>> Subscribing to PhoneEvent <<< 8c820520-06d4-49e3-ba41-13d0638bfbfc
>
> 4 >>> Subscribing to OnCreateCtiConf <<< 8c820520-06d4-49e3-ba41-13d0638bfbfc
>
> 5 >>> Waiting for task result. <<< 8c820520-06d4-49e3-ba41-13d0638bfbfc
>
> 70855 >>> Received event: OnCreateCTIConf : No message <<< **7afc50d3-c33d-4c39-a84c-132feeefefa5**
>
> 70855 >>> OnCreateCtiConf was null, CANNOT fire event. <<< **7afc50d3-c33d-4c39-a84c-132feeefefa5**

If you notice in the second output, the event we're expecting to receive is being captured by the previous instance of our .NET object!

I have made sure I'm setting our .NET object to `Nothing` in VB6 as soon as possible on shutdown, but it doesn't seem to fix the issue. I will say it did seem to alleviate it slightly, in that we go from 50/50 success/failure to something more like 75/25, but this could be confirmation bias on my part, so I can't say for sure.

In reading about .NET/COM interop (specifically [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f07c8z1c(v=vs.110).aspx) article), i see there is only one CCW per type of object, regardless of how many instances may be alive for it, and the reference counter is maintained on the CCW. So at this point I'm wondering if the GC is missing the previous instance as ready-to-collect because we get another instance of our .NET object via the CCW pretty soon thereafter (e.g. app crashes and then is immediately reopened), thus the ref counter is not 0, and since the GC only sees the CCW, it has no idea there is more than one instance behind it? I'm not sure if this even makes sense.

I can't be the only one who has needed deterministic release of a .NET object exposed to COM like this, so how does everyone else do it?

Please let me know if more examples/clarification are needed, I'll be happy to provide!

Thanks,

**EDIT:**

Found something interesting. I don't think the object itself is being left uncollected, but somehow the event handler for the event with this issue is. Using WinDbg, on a test that has this issue, I dumped the heap for this object and found the following:

```
0:003> !dumpheap -stat -type MyApp.ClickToDial.Phone
Statistics:
      MT    Count    TotalSize Class Name
038492c4        1           24 MyApp.ClickToDial.Phone+<>c__DisplayClass77_0
03848b8c        1           32 MyApp.ClickToDial.Phone+OnCallReleasedHandler
03848aa8        1           32 MyApp.ClickToDial.Phone+OnCallTransferredHandler
038488e0        1           32 MyApp.ClickToDial.Phone+OnLoginAgentConfHandler
038487fc        1           32 MyApp.ClickToDial.Phone+OnLogoutAgentConfHandler
03848718        1           32 MyApp.ClickToDial.Phone+OnSendDtmfConfHandler
03848634        1           32 MyApp.ClickToDial.Phone+OnGetCtiDataConfHandler
03848550        1           32 MyApp.ClickToDial.Phone+OnInitiateConferenceConfHandler
0384846c        1           32 MyApp.ClickToDial.Phone+OnCancelConferenceConfHandler
03848388        1           32 MyApp.ClickToDial.Phone+OnMakeCallConfHandler
038482a4        1           32 MyApp.ClickToDial.Phone+OnCompleteConferenceConfHandler
038481c0        1           32 MyApp.ClickToDial.Phone+OnCallConferencedHandler
038480dc        1           32 MyApp.ClickToDial.Phone+OnErrorHandler
03847ff8        1           32 MyApp.ClickToDial.Phone+OnCallDroppedHandler
03847f14        1           32 MyApp.ClickToDial.Phone+OnCallEstablishedHandler
038489c4        3           96 MyApp.ClickToDial.Phone+OnCreateCtiConfHandler
03844ac4        1          116 MyApp.ClickToDial.Phone
Total 19 objects
```

If you look at the number of items for `MyApp.ClickToDial.Phone+OnCreateCtiConfHandler` (the event right at the center of this issue), this is coincidentally the number of tests I ran until I encountered this issue.

I'm really not sure how that's even possible. Below is my implementation of all this, perhaps someone more experienced can see the issue?

This is the entry gate to our implementation. You first call this before you can call anything else. We need to receive the `OnCreateCtiConf` event before we can call `LoginAgent`. We have to instantiate the underlying `CTISoftphone` in this method, and not the constructor of our class, because the `CTISoftphone` constructor requires the agent extension, which we don't have when we're instantiating our class, hence the need to wait for this event.

```
public bool AgentLogin(string extension, string agentId, string password)
{
    writeTrace($"Entered {nameof(AgentLogin)}");
    _extension = extension;
    _agentId = agentId;
    try
    {
        writeTrace($"Creating {nameof(CTISoftphone)}");
        _phone = new CTISoftphone($"ext={extension},logFile={Settings.LogLocation}");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        writeTrace($"Caught exception: {ex.GetType()} | {ex.Message}");
        //this one might get lost since we haven't subscribed to CTISoftphone.PhoneEvent yet.
        OnError?.Invoke($"{_wrapperLogPrefix} Unable to create CTISoftPhone. The error was: {ex.Message}");
        return false;
    }

    writeTrace($"Subscribing to {nameof(CTISoftphone.PhoneEvent)}");
    _phoneEventHandler = new CTISoftphone.PhoneEventHandler(cti_phone_event);
    _phone.PhoneEvent += _phoneEventHandler;

    var are = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    var task = new Task(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            writeTrace("Calling LoginAgent");
            _phone.LoginAgent(agentId, password);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    });
    task.ContinueWith((t) => are.Set());

    var task_handler = new OnCreateCtiConfHandler(task.Start);

    writeTrace("Subscribing to OnCreateCtiConf");
    OnCreateCtiConf += task_handler;
    writeTrace("Waiting for task result");
    are.WaitOne();
    writeTrace("Unsubscribing from OnCreateCtiConf");
    OnCreateCtiConf -= task_handler;

    return true;
}
```

You'll notice there's only actually one event coming from `CTISoftphone`, which we subscribe to above. This event, `PhoneEvent`, passes an enum with the type of event being sent, and we process it locally in our `cti_phone_event` method, which is below (the `OnCreateCtiConf` event has different syntax for debug purposes here).

```
private void cti_phone_event(CTISoftphone.CTIEvent type, string info)
{
    writeTrace($"Received event: {type} : {(string.IsNullOrEmpty(info) ? "No message" : info)}");
    switch (type)
    {
        case CTISoftphone.CTIEvent.OnMakeCallConf:
            OnMakeCallConf?.Invoke();
            break;
        case CTISoftphone.CTIEvent.OnCompleteConferenceConf:
            OnCompleteConferenceConf?.Invoke();
            break;
        case CTISoftphone.CTIEvent.OnCancelConferenceConf:
            OnCancelConferenceConf?.Invoke();
            break;
        case CTISoftphone.CTIEvent.OnCallEstablished:
            OnCallEstablished?.Invoke();
            break;
        case CTISoftphone.CTIEvent.OnCallDropped:
            OnCallDropped?.Invoke();
            break;
        case CTISoftphone.CTIEvent.OnCallConferenced:
            OnCallConferenced?.Invoke();
            break;
        case CTISoftphone.CTIEvent.OnError:
            OnError?.Invoke(info);
            break;
        case CTISoftphone.CTIEvent.OnInitiateConferenceConf:
            OnInitiateConferenceConf?.Invoke();
            break;
        case CTISoftphone.CTIEvent.OnGetCTIDataConf:
            OnGetCtiDataConf?.Invoke();
            break;
        case CTISoftphone.CTIEvent.OnSendDTMFConf:
            OnSendDtmfConf?.Invoke();
            break;
        case CTISoftphone.CTIEvent.OnLogoutAgentConf:
            OnLogoutAgentConf?.Invoke();
            break;
        case CTISoftphone.CTIEvent.OnLoginAgentConf:
            OnLoginAgentConf?.Invoke();
            break;
        case CTISoftphone.CTIEvent.OnCreateCTIConf:
            if (OnCreateCtiConf != null)
            {
                writeTrace("OnCreateCtiConf was not null, firing event");
                OnCreateCtiConf();
            }
            else
            {
                writeTrace("OnCreateCtiConf was null, CANNOT fire event");
            }
            break;
        case CTISoftphone.CTIEvent.OnReleaseCallConf:
            OnCallReleased?.Invoke();
            break;
        case CTISoftphone.CTIEvent.OnCallTransferred:
            OnCallTransferred?.Invoke();
            break;
        default:
            OnError?.Invoke($"{_wrapperLogPrefix} Received unknown CTI event type: {type}");
            break;
    }
}
```

Lastly, I did implement `IDisposable` to manually unsubscribe events as suggested (though this doesn't seem to make a difference). Below are the `Dispose` and `Phone` destructor implementations.

```
public void Dispose()
{
    writeTrace("Dispose called");
    if (_phone != null)
        _phone.PhoneEvent -= _phoneEventHandler;
    _phone = null;
    _ctiData = null;

    OnCallEstablished = null;
    OnCallDropped = null;
    OnError = null;
    OnCallConferenced = null;
    OnCompleteConferenceConf = null;
    OnMakeCallConf = null;
    OnCancelConferenceConf = null;
    OnInitiateConferenceConf = null;
    OnGetCtiDataConf = null;
    OnSendDtmfConf = null;
    OnLogoutAgentConf = null;
    OnLoginAgentConf = null;
    OnCreateCtiConf = null;
    OnCallTransferred = null;
    OnCallReleased = null;
}

~Phone()
{
    writeTrace("Destructor called");
    Dispose();
}
```

So somehow it seems my events aren't being unsubscribed from like I'm expecting. How could this be? Is there something else here that I'm missing?

Also, as an additional check, I dumped the heap for the underlying `CTISoftphone` type to make sure the event/object counts made sense there, and they appear to (from the same session as the WinDbg output above):

```
0:003> !dumpheap -stat -type Avaya.APS.CTD.
Statistics:
      MT    Count    TotalSize Class Name
03846d64        1           32 Avaya.APS.CTD.CTISoftphone+PhoneEventHandler
03846bf0        1          108 Avaya.APS.CTD.CTISoftphone
Total 2 objects
```

Thoughts? Again, thanks in advance!

Comment: If I understand, you are receiving events in your .NET object.  At some point, you had to subscribe to the events to be able to receive them.  Did you unsubscribe to them?  Subscription adds a reference--whether it is the COM kind or .NET kind.  The fact that you are still receiving events says to me that you are still subscribed to the events.  I recommend unsubscribing events as well.

Comment: I suspect that @JoeWillcoxson is correct concerning event subscriptions.  Have you tried running your VB6 app via Visual Studio to debug the .Net class? i.e. Under Project Properties->Debug Tab->Start Action->Start external program (your VB6 executable).  You have mentioned the GC, Have you implemented a forced collection?  As debug test, you could implement a destructor in your class and verify that it is run on a forced GC collection; this will allow you to determine if supposedly un-referenced  instances are released.

Comment: VB6 was "managed" long before .NET. Setting a VB6's object's reference to nothing is useless unless the underlying COM object reference system is very buggy. Since it's a .NET object, this is useless. In fact, since both worlds are managed, you shouldn't have to do anything in the normal course of operation. The problem (calls from another instance) is probably due to your code. Anything unmanaged around? Is everything VB6 and .NET? Any custom threads started? COM objects threading model? Difficult to help more w/o some reproducing code.

Comment: Alright, so I implemented `IDisposable` and unsubscribe from all events in `Dispose`. This seems to work, but I think it's more of a byproduct and not because the GC is actually picking these objects up (e.g. if none of the orphaned objects have live events, they can't capture anything by mistake). This feels more like a hack, and I'd still love to know the 'right' way to do this.

Comment: @SimonMourier , the only unmanaged resource being used is a log file, and I only grab a handle to it right when logging. Regarding threading, yes there are other threads in the .NET object - we have one consuming events from a phone system. I haven't set a threading model myself yet, so the .NET object is still MTA and VB6 is STA (I don't fully understand these, so perhaps I'm not setting this correctly?). I agree with you the problem is likely in my code, this is the first time I've worked with COM and .NET, plus I'm sure I'm not the first person with this problem.

Comment: If you used standard settings for COM threading (c# MTA, VB6 STA) and not tweaked it by yourself, it should be ok. I would really have a look to what you do with threads. But again, w/o a piece of code, it's difficult to go further.

Comment: @SimonMourier I added the implementation above, as well as some new debug info I've found. If you get a sec to take a look, it would be greatly appreciated! Regarding my threading model, I am using defaults all around, so I believe currently C# is MTA and VB6 is STA like you said. I did test setting my C# code to STA to see if it made a difference (it didn't), but after reading more into the apartment model, I think that approach was fundamentally flawed anyway. Thanks again!

Comment: Few things: 1. Implementing Dispose will do nothing if you don't use it yourself (with `using` or explicit Dispose somewhere). 2. Your Dispose method is not thread safe (_phone could change in the middle of its execution). 3. Settings [Event] = null is not good to unsubscribe, you must use a `-=` with a defined fixed method (delegate) instance (like you do with _phone.PhoneEvent)

Comment: Hmm alright. The other side of this setup is a VB6 app (hence all the COM support), and in this app on shutdown, I am calling Dispose. Alongside that, all the event subscriptions are added in the VB6 app.This is setup via a second interface containing event methods, and then a decoration of `[ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(IClickToDialEvents))]` is added to the master `Phone` class. This allows us to use these like VB6 events (e.g. `Phone_OnCreateCtiConf` in VB6). This would be why I'm setting to null rather than explicitly unsubscribing each handler.